# How to run python in 32 bit on 64 bit kernel?

Tags: python, python-2.7, 32bit-64bit

I want to use an app but it requires 32 bit python (running in 64 bit gives `wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32`). How to run it 32 bit to make it work?

```
Architecture: x86-64
Python version: 2.7.12
OS: Ubuntu Server 14.04
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+run+python+in+32+bit+on+64+bit+kernel%3F&oq=How+to+run+python+in+32+bit+on+64+bit+kernel%3F&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.565j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

You could simply run a 32bit Ubuntu inside a `VirtualBox` or some other virtual machine. I think there are some ready to use images from `Vagrant`, too: [Link](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/hashicorp/boxes/precise32)